# Unable to set $from variable in mail function in PHP

Tags: php, html, email

I have following code for a form

```
<input type=text name=sender maxlength="50"/>
<input type=email name=mail />
<input type=text name=title maxlength="150"/>
<textarea name=issue rows=6></textarea>
<button name="submit"  type=submit>Submit</button>

<?php
if  (!empty($_REQUEST['sender'])&&!empty($_REQUEST['mail'])&&!empty($_REQUEST['issue']) &&!empty($_REQUEST['title'])) {
$sender=$_REQUEST['sender'];
$email=$_REQUEST['mail'];
$issue=$_REQUEST['issue'];  
$title=$_REQUEST['title'];
$from="$sender : $email";
mail("mail to send to", $title, $issue, $from);
}
?>
```

Now, the problem is I get ipg.apnasikkacom as name and ipg.apnasikkacom@boscustweb2803.eigbox.net as email address. Why is this happening?

Comment: Probably this is what you filled in the form??

Comment: first off all try with `var_dump` all your variables.

Comment: I don't see form tags; post method and you really should use quotes for your elements. Do take the time to read the manual before attempting anything http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: you're NOT setting a `from` header. you're setting something like `foo@example.com: bar@whatever.net`, which means absolutely nothing to the MTA. It has to be `From: foo@example.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$from` variable should actually be a [list of headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), separated by newlines.  It just so happens that one of the headers to send is also a `From` header.

How you've built the from header is incorrect.  If I put my name in your search box along with my email, that header would look like:

```
watcher: me@domain.com
```

It should actually look more like this:

```
From: watcher <me@domain.com>
```

You can find out more information about the structure of the `From` header in [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.2).

Comment: Too many unknowns in OP's posted code. Missing form tags, post method and who knows if they're using Ajax.

Comment: I agree, to me this was the most obvious thing at issue and had to do the most with his question.

Comment: *If I had a nickel....* lol I think you know the rest of how that expression goes. I'm just hoping OP's not going to come back and say: *"but it doesn't work"* - How many times have we seen that before? ;-)

Comment: The form tags are there I just did not write them here.